# How do I remove the toolbar out of my android app?

Tags: android

The title basically says everything. I want to remove this:

[image]

from my application. I am using a tabbed activity.

*What I already tried to do:*

I tried to use `getActionBar.hide()` in my onCreate() method and I tried to change the style/theme of the app in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

*This code in my tabbed app needs the toolbar(so I can't remove it from the layout):*

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Comment: remove the toolbar from the main xml.

Comment: That doesn't work with my tabbed activity, because it gives me errors in my MainActivity. The ViewPager does not work this way :/ @sumandas

Comment: Can you please share code

Comment: Are you using Toolbar ?

Comment: @VinothVino I have no use for it that is why I want to delete it.

Comment: Use getSupportActionBar instead

Comment: thanks @JorgeMendez I read about this, but someone said it is just necessary if minsdk is lower than 11 so I didn't try it. It worked.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot if you changed your app's style to not have the actionbar, and you are setting a custom toolbar (through setSupportActionBar), then you should be use getSupportActionBar or your custom toolbar reference everytime you want to interact with it

Comment: @JorgeMendez post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getSupportActionBar` instead.

If you changed your apps style to not have the actionbar and you are setting a custom toolbar(through `setSupportActionBar()`), then you should be using `getSupportActionBar()` or your custom toolbar reference everytime you want to interact with it.

If you are using AppCompat that you have to always use `getSupportActionBar()` and you also have to use it if the API level is lower than 11.